# More content after background-image

Tags: html, css, flexbox, centering

Sorry if my question is not worded the best. I am still getting into CSS and HTML and learning the correct terminology. Anyways, I am creating a homepage for my portfolio and to center the text on top of my image on the homepage I created a div and applied background-image to the CSS. Inside of the div I added text and a scroll down arrow.

Now I want to create the next portion of my site but with a white background, not the image. What should I do? I created a div for my second page and when I add elements the same background appears. Thanks.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.back {
  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/9WgJg0G.gif);
  background-size: cover;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  z-index: 1;
}

.text {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-top: 37vh;
  font-size: 8vh;
  z-index: 9999;
  color: #f39dbc;
  text-shadow: 6px 6px #8ccddb;
}

.pageone {
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: .75vh;
}

.scroll {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-top: 27vh;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Saira+Semi+Condensed" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="pageone">
    <div class="back">
      <div class="text">
        <h1>1080</h1>
      </div>

      <div class="scroll">
        <img src="scrolldown.png" alt="" id="scroll" />
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="pagetwo">

  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: just remove `position: fixed` from `.back`?

Answer (score 0):

Your `.pagetwo` div has nothing in it and no styles - I've added a height to it, and additionally removed `position: fixed` from the `.back` element (which was making that element fixed with the viewport when scrolling).

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.back {
  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/9WgJg0G.gif);
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  z-index: 1;
}

.text {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-top: 37vh;
  font-size: 8vh;
  z-index: 9999;
  color: #f39dbc;
  text-shadow: 6px 6px #8ccddb;
}

.pageone {
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: .75vh;
}

.scroll {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-top: 27vh;
}

.pagetwo {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Saira+Semi+Condensed" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="pageone">
    <div class="back">
      <div class="text">
        <h1>1080</h1>
      </div>

      <div class="scroll">
        <img src="scrolldown.png" alt="" id="scroll" />
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="pagetwo">

  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks, can't believe I missed that. I forgot about that position:fixed. I meant to have background-attachment: fixed. To create a parallax effect